# How to make a single query to check if a contact has a phone number and is present in some group say "abc"?

Tags: android

I want to make a query to check if a contact has any kind of phone number and is present in a particular group or not?

Comment: could you more specificate problem? where you have contacts, form etc...

Comment: OK i only want to check if a contact has a phone number or not??how to query for that?

Comment: i asked for where you have contats... in database? or where?

Comment: ya contacts are in normal android content provider only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure about Group but about containing minimum 1 phone number you can prepare a query like this

```
Uri URI = ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI;
String[] projection = {ContactsContract.Contacts._ID, ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME, ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER};
String selection = ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER + "=1";

Cursor mContactCursor = .getContentResolver().query(URI, projection, selection, null, null);
```

Remember to add permission in your manifest.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
```

Comment: updated, and also add permission in manifest.